# How to add reverse dns record on cloudflare

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns, ptr-record, cloudflare

I need to set PTR record on my cloudflare account, because all outgoing mails are going to spam. I do not see ptr record in my cloudflare account. Can I use txt/srv record instead?

Comment: First result on Google for "cloudflare reverse dns": https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168596-How-do-I-add-a-PTR-record-to-CloudFlare-

Comment: "CloudFlare also does not support rDNS." But im curious if I can add it as txt

Comment: What makes you think that'd work? Are you confusing SPF/DKIM records with PTR records?

Answer (score 4):

You have to ask your hosting provider to set up the PTR record for your server.

As PTR records are maintained by the entities owning the IP address blocks, they cannot be set up via forward DNS providers like Cloudflare.

Comment: This answer is out-of-date as of March 1998, since PTR records can be delegated via RFC 2317. This is what most providers I've used to, so I actually need for my DNS server to support PTR records.